# Inspecting elements on localhost doesn't display element dimensions

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I'm using both "Regular" Firefox as well as the Developer edition. At the moment I'm developing a website locally (using node.js/gulp) and am experiencing a weird... maybe a bug? Whenever I inspect elements in the Developer Edition through the developer tools, the little balloon showing the name of the element and its dimensions doesn't show up. It does show on any other website I try in FF DevEd, and it also shows when I load the localhost page in FF Regular.

Currently I'm on FF DevEd 54.0a2 <s>(2017-04-04)</s> (2017-04-07) (32-bit).

[image: This little grey popup (#text | 4 x 16) does not show on localhost:7777 in FF DevEd]
This little grey popup (#text | 4 x 16) does not show on localhost:7777 in FF DevEd

## UPDATE

I noticed that I *did* see the balloon at the top of the page, but not anymore when I get lower in the content. Apparently I'm using styling that affects the Developer Options Balloon...!?

[image: the balloon is stuck at that position]

Is there any info on the styles that the Developer Tools use for their elements?

Comment: To me this sounds like a bug, but I cannot reproduce this on DevEdition 54.0a2 (2017-04-06). Are there any errors shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl+Shift+J) related to the DevTools? Does it work for you on a [new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Managing%20profiles)?

Comment: There's a bit more to it I think... I've updated to 54.0a2 (2017-04-06) as well, and noticed that I did see the balloons at the top of the page, but not lower in the content... apparenty they get placed "wrong". I'll update the question with this new info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously a bug in Firefox Developer Edition 54.0a2. I could track it down to the [change that caused this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1312103) using [mozregression](https://harthur.github.io/mozregression/) and filed [bug 1354494](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1354494) for it.

**Update:**
My bug report got closed as duplicate of [bug 1349275](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1349275), which already got fixed for Firefox 55.

Comment: Ya, you're right. Your bug report did not entirely match what I saw happening so I opened another one myself, and with some research it turned out to be fixed in the nightly build. Mine was eventuelly closed as duplicate to the same as yours.